# Settings class implementation

Tags: java, parsing, serialization, reflection, configuration

I have a `settings.txt` file with the following format:

```
property=value
another_property=value

category.sub_category.property_name=value
```

And a `Settings` class that reads the properties out of this file and uses reflection to assign values to the corresponding fields within the class and it's subclasses:

```
public final class Settings {
    private Settings(){}

    public static void loadSettingsFile(){

        String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/settings.txt";
        try {
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(dir));
            for(String str : lines){
                String[] property = str.split("=");
                if(property.length == 2)
                    setProperty(property[0], property[1]);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Settings file not found");
        }
    }

    public static void setProperty(String name, String value){
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            Class target = Settings.class;
            int lastDot = name.lastIndexOf('.');

            if(lastDot != -1){

                String classPath = Settings.class.getPackage().getName();
                classPath += ".Settings$" + name.substring(0, lastDot).replace('.', '$');

                target = Class.forName(classPath);
                name = name.substring(lastDot + 1);
            }

            Field property = target.getField(name);

            switch (property.getType().getName()) {
            case "boolean":
                property.setBoolean(null, value.equals("true"));
                break;
            case "int":
                property.setInt(null, Integer.parseInt(value));
                break;
            case "double":
                property.setDouble(null, Double.parseDouble(value));
                break;
            case "java.lang.String":
                property.set(null, value);
                break;
            case "[Ljava.lang.String;":
                property.set(null, value.split(","));
                break;
            case "[I":
                String[] values = value.split(",");
                int[] ints = new int[values.length];
                for(int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++)
                    ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(values[i]);
                property.set(null, ints);
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Could not set property '" + name + "' - unsupported field type: " + property.getType().getName());
                return;
            }

        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Can't find or access property: " + name);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | SecurityException e) {
            System.out.println("Can't set property '" + name + "' to " + value);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Can't set property '" + name + "' to " + value);
        }
    }






    /*------------------------------
       settings fields start here
    ------------------------------*/

    public static String mode = "training AI";

    public static class map{
        private map(){}

        public static int width = 35;
        public static int height = 30;
        public static int random_walls = 10;
    }

    public static class training{
        private training(){}

        public static String algorithm = "genetic";
        public static String[] ann_files = null;

        public static boolean override_ann_file_settings = false;
        public static String sensory_input = "basic";
        public static int smell_precision = 1;
        public static boolean interfering_outputs = false;

        // more settings...
    }

    // more subclasses containing settings...
}
```

I find it convenient to be able to access these settings OOP style from anywhere in my program, I prefer it over a `Settings.get(String name)` solution because that way the IDE shows me what settings there are so I don't have to remember all their names.

Are there any disadvantages to this solution?

Also I'm not sure about the naming convention, should I make the `setProperty(...)` method convert property names to match normal Java naming convention or is it ok as it is now?

```
category.sub_category.property_name
convert name to:
Settings.Category.SubCategory.propertyName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always use curly braces even if your loop/if statement contains 1 line.

You're catching all Exceptions and assuming it's due to the file not being found. You should be catching `FileNotfoundException` instead. Alternatively you could check if the File is found or not.

What if the property format is invalid? E.G 2 '=' signs or 0. Currently you wouldn't throw or log any error and silently ignore it. I'd suggest at least LOGGING something